# Quadratic transformation with only ordinary singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have to find the quadratic transformation of the following curve

$\ C : y^2z^2 - x^3z - x^4 - y^4 = 0$

with only ordinary singularities. 
Any idea about how to solve this exercise?